# I need glowing outline around button in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am working on a project in unity5, while I am making a menu contain buttons, I need button to make glowing outline, need help in this regard.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otNn8.png)
same in the picture, I need button like this in my Unity 5

Comment: Simplest solution and recommended one is to add a second image below. Just like in the example.

Comment: that will not react when we press the button, I need to add a button with glowing outline normal state, and high intensity glow outline when pressed

Comment: @MuhammadAmeen What are talking about? I think Everts meant you should make your glowing Button in a photoshop or some 2D app then simply put it in Target Graphic property of the Button in Unity. This is better as it will reduce render calls.

Comment: Indeed, the point is just to draw a basic Texture2D. Make it inactive at start, and then you can use OnPointerEnter/Exit/Down/XXX to activate it. Or use SpriteSwap so you have two versions of your button, one glowing, and one normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using canvas you can do that without using any functions or events it can be easily done select button in inspector you will see button (script) component set transition to sprite swap and drop the desired sprite in pressed sprite box.